Electric charge conveyor trap
Normally one cannot trap both positive and negative charge within the same region by using electrostatic confinement as one charge would be attracted and the other repelled.
I was wondering is it possible to achieve this by using an electrostatic system that moves.
In both drawings the bottom grey conductor symbolizes a tube filled with low temperature neutral plasma. The aim is to achieve a higher plasma concentration at one end of the tube. Can someone comment on what would happen in both of the situation , both with the pulley type charge belt with charged red squares and also with the linear charged squares.
I personally have a feeling that the linear squares that move in a straight line would work better.
I wonder what happens to the charge that is accumulated by any individual square that passes by as it leaves the tube meanwhile the next (previous) charged square is approaching, does the charge in the tube "switch over" to the next square as the previous leaves away from the tube?



The charged blocks would definitely have an effect on the plasma, but plasmas can shield applied electrostatic influences, the influence of the field of the blocks would only penetrate the plasma on the order of something called the Debye length. This shielding is weaker on plasmas that are hotter or denser. So, you bring a positively charged brick nearby. This will repel some of the nuclei and attract some of the electrons. Then you begin moving the bricks- this will move the region of deficient ions and excess electrons. However, the electrons "respond" much faster because of something called relaxation time, which is a measure of how quickly the plasma will respond to a perturbation from some change. If you keep moving bricks past over and over, the plasma will definitely have some nuclei jostled towards the left of the tube, some to the right, and the electrons similarly. To get a consistent piling up anywhere you'd have to get the timing just right with the relaxation. But then! Piled up electrons in one place attract the nuclei... piled up nuclei in one place attract the electrons... you will almost certainly excite what are called Ion Acoustic and Langmuir waves in this plasma. It will be a noisy messy situation but might still have some net piling up of nuclei- again if you get the timing just so.
You are correct that pure electrostatic trapping is not possible- but if one adds in time dependent (non-static) fields, or inertial effects, trapping is indeed possible. You should read into inertial electrostatic confinement and quadrupole ion trapping.
